# scaling in chipmunk physics engine

Tags: objective-c

i don't know how to scale the UIiMageview class object in chipmunk engine

i used snap code as example

Answer (score 1):

UIImageView is a CocoaTouch class, part of the standard iPhone SDK and not part of Chipmunk. You should look in Apple's documentation for information on it.

http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UIImageView_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: thank you slembcke i scaled the UIMageview ,i used the normal method UIITrnasform make scale now its working,before i placed the scale code in wrong area , now i solved that problem, thanks for u r valuable reply